# Sublime text not recognizing "-std=c++17" even after upgrading to GCC-6.3.0

Tags: c++, c++17, sublimetext3, mingw

I am using sublime text for compiling and running c++ files. But sublime text is not recognizing C++17 when I am trying to compile build using "-std=c++17". I have made below build system in sublime text :

```
{
"cmd": ["g++.exe", "-std=c++17", "${file}",
        "-o", "${file_base_name}.exe",
        "&&", "${file_base_name}.exe<inputf.in>outputf.out"],
"shell":true,
"working_dir":"$file_path",
"selector":"source.cpp"
}
```

Below error message is getting displayed in sublime text when I use above build system to compile any cpp file:

```
cc1plus.exe: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++17"
[Finished in 177ms]
```

I have checked and made sure that it is picking up GCC-6.3.0 only from command prompt.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.985]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\hp>g++ --version
g++ (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I have tried using "-std=c++1z" instead of "-std=c++17" but this is also not helping.

Interestingly, I am able to run the g++ command using "-std=c++17" when I directly use it in command prompt. C++ files are getting compiled without any issues from command prompt using "-std=c++17". Below command is working fine when I am using command prompt:

```
g++.exe -std=c++17 ystest.cpp
```

Comment: Try adding  `"--version"` to the build system config to double check what version Sublime is picking up.  It might be different from the one you see from the command line.

Comment: Well, GCC 6 supports only a few C++17 features. So I am uncertain what is the aim at any rate.

Comment: You're upgrading to a GCC 6.3, which is 5 years old, so I wonder what version you used previously. Why not upgrade to a recent GCC version, like 9 or 10?

Answer (score 0):

### Setting up the Environment

- Install MinGW Compiler MinGW is a native Windows port of the GNU Compiler Collection (GCC). Install the latest MinGW compiler, after downloading from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/), this is the latest C++17 supported version 9. Your path should preferably be C:\MinGW. Finally, add the bin directory, C:\MinGW\bin **to the System PATH.** In other words make it to environment variables.
- Create a build system
  Sublime Text provides build systems to allow users to run external programs. Create a new build system for Sublime Text for setting up C++ compilation.
  Go to Tools > Build System > New Build System. Paste the following code in the file and save it.

```
{
"cmd": ["g++.exe","-std=c++17", "${file}", "-o", "${file_base_name}.exe", "&&" , "${file_base_name}.exe<inputf.in>outputf.in"],
"shell":true,
"working_dir":"$file_path",
"selector":"source.cpp"
}
```

This can be used for piping input from the inputf.in file, and output to the outputf.in file. Note that this uses the -std=c++17 flag to enable the latest features of C++17. If you don't want this or want to use C++14, replace this with the -std=c++14 flag.